# linear transformation of the classical projective plane taking a circle to a hyperbola

Tags: linear-transformations, projective-geometry, projective-space

Consider a circle with equation $x^2+y^2=1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and hyperbola $xy=1$. Then with homogenenous coordinates we have that the circle has equation $X^2-Y^2-Z^2=0$ which gives the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

For the hyperbola we have the equation $X^2-XY=1$ so we homogenize the matrix to look like
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I would like to map the circle to the hyperbola with a matrix $M$ such that $M^{-1}AM^{-T}=B$ where $-T$ denotes the inverse transpose of $M$. The problem is I am not sure how to get $M$. If we take the base points $(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ , only two of these belong to the circle over $\mathbb{R}$ and the circle has no points at infinity. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the equation of the circle is $X^2+Y^2-Z^2=0$ correctly, so $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Also, the equation of the hyperbola is $$XY-Z^2=0,$$ so $$B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now we will find the projective transformation that sends the hyperbola to the circle. We will use that a conic is determined by its three points and the tangents at two of these points. So we will send three points and two corresponding tangents of the hyperbola to points and tangents of the circle.

First, $[1,0,0]$ is on the hyperbola, let its image be $[1,0,1]$.

$[0,1,0]$ is also on the hyperbola, let its image be $[0,1,1]$.

The tangents of the hyperbola at these points are the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, their intersection is $[0,0,1]$. Let its image be $[1,1,1]$, because the tangents of the circle at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ meet at $(1,1)$.

Finally, $[1,1,1]$ is on the hyperbola, let its image be an arbitrary point of the circle, for example $[-1,0,1]$.

We use that in the coloumns of the matrix of a linear transformation we find the images of the base vectors. Thus our desired matrix is of form $$M=\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & c \\ 0 & b & c \\ a & b & c\end{bmatrix}.$$ (For example, the first coloumn is $[a,0,a]$, because the image of $[1,0,0]$ is $[1,0,1]$, which is the same point as $[a,0,a]$ for any $a\neq 0$.)

Since the image of $[1,1,1]$ is $[-1,0,1]$, we get the equation $$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & c \\ 0 & b & c \\ a & b & c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Solving this equation we get $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=-2$. Thus the matrix of the projective transformation that sends the hyperbola to the circle is
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}.$$
You can check that if $N$ is the inverse of this matrix, then $NAN^T=B$ (up to some factor).

Comment: Sorry about the homogeneous equations - I see what I did wrong! How did you decide to map points $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$? Also, I checked and $(-2)NAN^T$ does not equal $B$, in fact I get a matrix almost like $B$, except the last coordinate in the matrix equals $-0.5$.

Comment: I chose [1,0,0] and [0,1,0], because it is the easiest to compute the matrix of a projective transformation if we know the image of the basis points [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]. In this case we are "lucky", because the first two points are on the hyperbola.

Comment: I understand we can take the base points, I'm wondering why did you choose those images specifically.

Comment: I just did another calculation and $((-2)NAN^T)^{-1}=B$. Why is this the case? Maybe because we are going from a hyperbola to a circle not the other way around?

Comment: Because I chose points on the circle as the images of these points, where it is simple to obtain the tangent line. (We are also "lucky" that the lines through [1,0,0], [0,0,1] and [0,1,0],[0,0,1] are tangents of the hyperbola, so we can choose the image of these lines as tangents of the circle.)

Comment: Yes, because of the base points it was easier to go from the hyperbola to the circle. If you want to transfrom the circle to the hyperbola, just use the inverse transformation.